# building website to store data with ability to query and filter

Tags: php, mysql, database, content-management-system

i have basic knowledge about programming and iam wondering if there is any script or CMS (for example "wordpress for blogging sites") that i can start with for building my website and add fields by simple way and connect data automatically to the database with the ability to query and filter and all possible operations on the database

Answer (score 0):

A simple web-based database would be MySQL, and you can design a web-based application to work with it using HTML and PHP.

Answer (score 0):

It is still possible if you use CMS like Wordpress, by creating another instance of wpdb class. then u can use their functions like insert, update and get_results for your CRUD purposes